# How to make changes in child component from parent?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input, angular5

In my angular application, i am having a file upload which is a child component and app component is parent component.

In **app.component.html** (Parent) i am having a single line code only which calls the child component like,

```
<app-profile-image></app-profile-image>
```

**In no way i cannot edit the child component in my real application** so please don't edit anything in child component (`profile-image.component`) because it is a library and i am not having any code of it.

**Working example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload-preview-6f4o8w

My requirement is, you can see in the child component (just see for ref),

```
<h4 class="success-message" *ngIf="url"> Uploaded Successfully </h4>
```

Which will be displayed if the profile picture was uploaded otherwise this text won't appear..

Everything is working but what happens was this text can be **visible only** if we upload the image and **again hover over the image**..

So the user not getting notified whether the image was uploaded unless he hover over the image again..

So how can i display the `success-message` below the profile image in the parent component (`app.component`) once the file was uploaded successfully.

Kindly help me to display the success message once the file was uploaded below the picture and not on hover **without touching anything in child component**..

Comment: The only thing you can only do if you don't want to change the child component is to make an http interceptor, and handle it inside in the http-interceptor service

Answer (score 0):

You might as well show the actual child component, this way you will be saving everyones' efforts. For the example you have shown, you can do with a reference variable of the child component in parent.

```
<app-profile-image #iAmNotReal></app-profile-image>
<h3> Success message can be displayed here </h3>

<b *ngIf="childComp?.url">Picture uploaded sucessfully</b>

export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('iAmNotReal') childComp;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload-preview-w5qwha?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: But i need to get rid of the message on hover because the same success message was already displayed at bottom.. Only at the bottom of picture i can have the ```success message``` ..

Comment: Also i will get problem with this way of approach because i need to display whatever text i am having in the child component.. I cannot hard code like this because for error message that will indicate what type of error it is and in what format the image needs to be.. It cannot be hard coded like this know??